# ngx Bootstrap manual close button

Tags: angular, frontend, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a a manual popover close button at the top right of the popover, using ngx-bootstrap. I do know that to add the x button, we would have to make use of &Times from bootstrap.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/close-icon/

However I do not know how to implement it to my title as I am trying to add it to the top right.

```js
 content: string = "content of popover ";
 Title: string = "Title of popover";
```

```html
 <a [popover]="content" container="body" placement="top" [popoverTitle]="Title" >Making this popover</a>
```

[image]

[This](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover) is the link I'm using. I'm using this example, the template and component.

[image]

My [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/EJdIrmXaVcZbsr0G8qKx/) basically, to put it simple, I need a X on the top right of the title.

Comment: what is the issue then?

Comment: Hi I editted my work accidently submitted my post too early, currently trying to add a x button to the top right of the title would need help doing it. @SandipPatel

Comment: May be you can share the code which would be easier to help.

Comment: @KarthickManoharan Hi I shared my code above is it enough? or do I have to share on plunker?

Comment: plunker would be great

Comment: @KarthickManoharan I'm unable to use ngxbootstrap in plunker, somehow the library just wouldn't load inside plunker, is there any other way to share my codes?

Comment: @KarthickManoharan managed to use plunker here is my link
https://embed.plnkr.co/EJdIrmXaVcZbsr0G8qKx/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Manage to do [it](https://plnkr.co/edit/NMjeFv5li5zWe6drBgD2?p=info) eventually, since popoverTitle only accepts string

```html
<div>
  <ng-template #popoverContent3>
    <div style="font-size:18px; font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-weight:bold;">
      <p>this is a title...
      <button type="button" (click)='pop2.hide()' class="close" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
     <p>The best looking pop over, with a TITLE!</p>  
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  
  <a  [popover]="popoverContent3" #pop2="bs-popover" placement="right">
   Pop over with title and a x button!
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

From [popover dynamic html](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover#dynamic-html) docs you can see `[popover]` accepts html inputs. you can create a desired custom popover content with appropriate style using the `ng-template` with id `eg: #popOverContent` and provide  the id as input to the `[popover]` like below.

```
 <a [popover]= "popOverContent" container="body" placement="right">
   this popover need a x on top
 </a>

 <ng-template #popOverContent>
   <span style="float:right">X</span>
   <p>Popped content.....</p>
 </ng-template>
```

You can replace these lines in your code for changes

**Update:**

You already have got the best possible solution in your plnkr demo. `X` can be placed anywhere by using CSS styles.

```
<a [popover]="popOverContent" container="body" #pop="bs-popover" 
  placement="right">this popover need a x on top
</a>

<ng-template #popOverContent>
  <button type="button" (click)='pop.hide()' class="close" aria-
  label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Popped content..without title

Comment: is it possible to use hide() function on <span style="float:right">X</span>

Comment: Might it be possible to use https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/close-icon/
To make a close button?

Comment: Manage it to do it by myself however I still need a x button with title, will continue it tomorrow, thanks for telling me to use ngtemplate,
This is my plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/urox2SggzTfQfkwJ8rT4?p=info

Comment: I'm still not able to make the x button at the title, using ng-template makes the title display "object Object" instead. 
Attached below is my plunker
https://embed.plnkr.co/NMjeFv5li5zWe6drBgD2/

Comment: `popoverTitle` only accepts `string` data's. In you example you are passing a template object which is why you see `[Object Object]` in the title. I have updated the answer too

Comment: Great! Did you do different approach?

Comment: yup, I declare it inside the ng-template by making use of the <div> tag and setting styles to bold to make look like a title, can see my plunker on top!

Comment: This one works for me, and we need to add ```container="body"``` in HTML